# Refactoring docxtemplater from server, the req json object stops be accessed in doc.setData()

Tags: json, node.js, object, express, docxtemplater

I am trying to refactor docxtemplater code out of my server file in node.  The req.body json object works fine there, and even can be console.logged *inside* the doc.setData() method.  However when I try to run the server I am getting this error:

```
firstName: data.firstName,
               ^      
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

This is my docxtemplater.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

function estateDoc (data) {

let content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'docxGen.docx'), 'binary');

let zip = new JSZip(content);

let doc = new Docxtemplater();
doc.loadZip(zip);

doc.setData({
  firstName: data.firstName,
  lastName: data.lastName,
  middleName: data.middleName,
  suffix: data.suffix,
  socialSecurity: data.socialSecurity,
  address: data.address,
  telephone: data.telephone,
  heir: data.heir
});
  try {
      doc.render()
  }
  catch (error) {
      var e = {
          message: error.message,
          name: error.name,
          stack: error.stack,
          properties: error.properties,
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify({error: e}));
      throw error;
  }
  var buf = doc.getZip()
               .generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});
  fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + '/doc-sender-catcher', 'output.docx'), buf)
};
estateDoc();

module.exports = {estateDoc};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm leaving this here for anyone new to refactoring in node.  Don't declare your function and then call it before you export and run it.  My problem was the last line where I was running the function with the data argument empty...